# How to mount local host directory in docker container using remote api

Tags: python, api, docker

So I'm using the docker remote api. I'm sending request from the host machine that's running the docker and it's listening on localhost and the usually unix socket.

So instead of using the docker cli command to start a container. I'm using `POST /containers/create` and `POST /containers/(id or name)/start` endpoints.

Does anyone know how to mount a local directory to a container. Specifically the equivalent of `docker run -d  --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py` command in the docker remote api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the following request, followed by a start:

```
POST /containers/create?name=web HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
       "Cmd": [ "python", "app.py" ],
       "Image": "training/webapp",
       "Volumes": {
         "/webapp": {}
       },
}
```